# content access + menu block => not shown all links in menu block

Tags: nodes, blocks

I have menu block and content access modules in my website, and I have some content types restricted and is working well. The problem is when a node is restricted, the link isn't shown and I want to show that link.

To show the links in menu block is important for me, because the user will know that there is content there and to access he has to acquire a membership.

I have tried the always shown module, but it only works in other menus (the normal drupal menu, TB megamenu ans superfish menu), I mean that in those menus it shows the hidden links, but it doens't work in menu block.

I need menu block, because I handle a principal menu, and menu block is my secondary menu, it shows after the 4th level.

How can I show all links in menu block module? (https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_block)

Thank you so much for all your answers, I really want to finish that page and for that I need all the help you can give it to me because I couldn't do by myself.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You should at least explain what you mean by _I have tried the always shown module_ and _show all link in menu block_.

Comment: Why would you display a link which can not be accessed?

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/182326, which should also work to answer this question ... PS to answer @PatrickScheffer 's comment: a possible answer could be like 'because the **customer** is asking for it' ... and another answer could be "to use such links as teasers" ... Good enough as a motivation?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens Of course those are good motivations. However, I've learned never to make assumptions so I'd prefer a little more information so I am better able to help the OP.

Comment: Thank you for the extra comment, seems like we have similar viewpoints. I also post similar comments to questions that at first don't seem to be clear enough (instead of just voting it right away as "unclear what you're asking). It avoids that anybody answering a question has to "guess" what the question really is about, with the risk that you're wasting your time if an answer is about a different question. I now hope that the OP-er here will do some extra effort to edit the question (to clarify it AbitMORE) ...